# How to make 2 videos side by side, centered, and responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, joomla3.0

I am trying to add 2 videos side by side which are centered and spaced out correctly, and then want to make them responsive with the second video dropping down below the first video so that it can appear stacked on mobile devices. My Html that I am working with is:

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="home1">
   <video width="400" height="300" poster="images/video.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none"> 
     <source type="video/mp4" src="images/stories/home1.mp4" /> 
   </video>
  </div>
  <div id="home2">
   <video width="400" height="300" poster="images/video.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none"> 
     <source type="video/mp4" src="images/stories/home2.mp4" /> 
   </video>
  </div> 
</div>
```

and my css so far is:

```
#wrapper { 
    width: 920px; 
    height: 350px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
} 

#home1 { 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px; 
    float: left; 
} 

#home2 { 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px; 
    float: right; 
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .home1 {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16/9 ratio */
        padding-top: 30px; /* IE6 workaround*/
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .home2 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Have you tried adding something to your media query to remove the floats and maximize the width - like, wrapper div { width: 100%; float: none; } edit: you'd actually need to be more specific since you're using #'s on the divs so #home1, #home2 { width: 100%; float: none; }

Comment: http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/pwkHj

Comment: That works well, @Evan

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications in your html and css, test it yourself.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <video id="home1" width="400" height="300" poster="images/video.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none"> 
        <source type="video/mp4" src="images/stories/home1.mp4" /> 
    </video>
    <video id="home2" width="400" height="300" poster="images/video.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none"> 
        <source type="video/mp4" src="images/stories/home2.mp4" /> 
    </video>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper { 
    width: 920px; 
    height: auto; 
    margin: 0 auto;
} 
#home1 { 
    width: 47.5%; 
    height: 300px; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 5%;
} 

#home2 { 
    width: 47.5%; 
    height: 300px; 
    float: left; 
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    #home1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        float: none;
    }
    #home2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jefferson thank you for the info much appreciated! I have tested it and it appears correctly on the mobile website with the videos below each other, but not on desktop view. What happens on desktop view is the videos are also below each other when they should be side by side / next to each other.

Comment: In the media query (max-width: 767px) try to adjust the max-width to your desired size of screen, I think 500px is a good number. So screens with width greater than 500px will no have videos below each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding something to your media query to remove the floats and maximize the width? edit: you might actually need to be more specific since you're using #'s on the divs so `#home1, #home2 { width: 100%; float: none; }` – example here http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/pwkHj